# Node.js: use Math methods without refer to module

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, require

In a scientific package running over Node.js I need to execute user provided mathematical expressions like "sin(2*PI*x)". Currently, it is implemented similar to:

```
// from input: s = "1+Math.sin(2*Math.PI*x)";
...
// regexp to verify "s" doesn't contains dangerous characters as '";
...
val f = new Function( 'x', s );
...
f(12);
```

The problem is user must type `Math.sin(3*x)` instead of a more simple `sin(3*x)`. Is there any way to skip this problem ?

If not possible, I will look for a "replace" call that constructs the string `1+Math.sin(3*x)` from `1+sin(3*x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look if `Math` has a property with the same name and replace the part with additional `Math.`.

```js
var string = "sin(3*x)+foo()+PI*Math.PI",
    result = string.replace(/[a-z][\d.a-z]*(?=\(|[^\da-z]|$)/ig, k => (k in Math ? 'Math.' : '') + k);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Nice idea to check if identifier is a property of Math. As regular expression, if no way to "import" all Math, I'm thinking on /\b[A-Za-z]\w*\b/g

Comment: This is something I will need to skip, for backward compatibility: "Math.PI" results in "Math.Math.PI"

Comment: do you need only methods?

Comment: then add a replacement for `/Math\.(?=Math\.)/g` with an empty string.

Comment: I'm trying replace( /\b[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9._]*\b/g, k => ( k in Math  ? 'Math.'+k : k ))

Comment: i habe never seen an underscore, but if it works for you, then fine.